# login with username or email in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on login template...but I want to make login with username as well as **email**.I got code with for that but it is not worked,it is as follow:

```
function login_with_email_address($username) {

    $user = get_user_by('email',$username);
    if(!empty($user->user_login))
        $username = $user->user_login;  
    return $username;
}
add_action('wp_authenticate','login_with_email_address',10,1);
```

I already put action in '**authenticate**' for email verification,it is as follow:

```
function check_user_status($user, $username, $password) {   

    if (in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        if (get_user_meta($user->ID, 'confirm_mail', true) == 1) { return $user; }
        else{ return new WP_Error('Account Not Active.');  }
    }
    else{ return $user; }
}
add_filter('authenticate','check_user_status', 30, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
 add_filter( 'authenticate', 'tcb_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );


   function tcb_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {
      if ( ! empty( $username ) && is_email( $username ) ) :
        if ( $user = get_user_by_email( $username ) )
          $username = $user->user_login;
      endif;

      return wp_authenticate_username_password( null, $username, $password );
    }
```